# Is the function convex or concave?

Tags: convex-analysis

I am trying to solve question below:
Is function
$$f(x, y, z) = x+y +z + \ln(xyz)$$
strongly convex or strongly concave in the
$A = \{ (x, y, z) | x > 0, y < 0, z < 0 \}$?
Also, determine the (possible) local and global extremes values?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Your function is differentiable, take the gradient.

Comment: Thanks! I did a Hessian matrix which said that f is a concave among A. I still wonder what is the effect of the (open?) set to the answer and what points are possible for extremes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to evaluate the signature of $Hf$ in the set of interest. On $A$, $$f(x,y,z)=x+y+z+\ln x+\ln(-y)+\ln(-z)$$ and therefore $$Hf(x,y,z)=\begin{pmatrix}-x^{-2}&0&0\\ 0&-y^{-2}& 0\\ 0&0& -z^{-2}\end{pmatrix}$$

Therefore the function is concave on $A$.

The critical points are solutions in $A$ to $\nabla f(x,y,z)=0$, i.e. $$\begin{cases}x>0\\ y<0\\ z<0\\ 1+\frac1x=0\\ 1+\frac1y=0\\ 1+\frac1z=0\end{cases}$$

So no critical points, meaning that the function has no local maxima or minima. It's clear that $\sup_{v\in A}f(v)=\infty$ and $\inf_{v\in A}f(v)=-\infty$.

Comment: This was really helpful! Can I ask for more information? How does my answer changes if the function is now (,,)=||+||+||+ln() with the absolute value signs?

Comment: @AadaSoikkeli I don't know about your answer. Mine would carry out the same way, with the appropriate changes to $\nabla f$.